# Problema com inputs do utilizador

Tags: java, scanner

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
public class FlagApplication {

    private Scanner keyboard;

    ....

    private void insertNewRegistry(){
       System.out.println("insira os dados de pessoa: nome, peso, altura, idade, sexo e bi.");

       String nome = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println("nome: " +nome);
       double peso = keyboard.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("peso: " +peso);
       int altura = keyboard.nextInt();
       System.out.println(altura);
       int idade = keyboard.nextInt();
       System.out.println(idade);
       char sexo = keyboard.next(".").charAt(0);
       System.out.println(idade);
       int bi = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    ....

}
```

O problema é que o primeiro input a ser assumido é logo o peso, em vez de ser o nome, ou seja, faz `System.out.println("nome: " +nome);` sendo que nome é vazio ('') e fica à espera do peso em vez de ficar primeiro à espera do nome

Comment: Tem como colocar o resto do código? A parte em que instancia o Scanner.

Comment: Editei, acho que está aí tudo o que é relevante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Patrick disse, sem o seu código completo não dá para saber ao certo o que está acontecendo. Mas a gente pode chutar!

Eu acho que você está dando um `enter` onde não deveria, na hora de inserir os dados.

Eu reescrevi parte do seu código, tentando reproduzir o erro:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EntraDados {

    private Scanner keyboard;

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("-------");

        System.out.print("Insira seu nome: ");
        String nome = keyboard.nextLine();


        System.out.print("Agora seu peso: ");
        double peso = keyboard.nextDouble();


        System.out.print("E a sua altura: ");
        int altura = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Insira a sua idade: ");
        int idade = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("E o seu sexo: ");
        char sexo = keyboard.next(".").charAt(0);

        System.out.println("-------");

        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
        System.out.println("Peso: " + peso);
        System.out.println("Altura: " + altura);
        System.out.println("Idade: " + idade);
        System.out.println("Sexo: " + sexo);

    }
}
```

[image: Execução de "EntraDados"]

Parece funcionar! Por favor inclua o seu código, caso a minha sugestão não sirva para você.

Answer (score 1):

Há uma possibilidade de ocorrer erros na leitura das variáveis quando se usa nextInt, nextDouble, nextFloat, etc... Eu penso que é porque o caracter 'enter' pode ser indevidamente convertido para número, assim gabunçando a leitura.

Eu sempre utilizo next() ou nextLine() e depois converto o número, desta forma:

```
double peso = Double.paraseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

int altura = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
```